# How to add listener in setup/render function to event 'update:myprop'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In vue 3, when a component `comp` emits an event `my-event`, a listener can be registered in the render function returned from setup:

```
import {  h, defineComponent, resolveComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
setup(props, ctx) {
   const myComp = resolveComponent('comp');
   return () => h(myComp, {
       onMyEvent(evt){
         console.log(evt);
       }
   });
})
```

How could a listener to an event such as `update:my-prop` be defined to achieve the equivalent behavior of a `v-model`?
I have tried with `onUpdateMyProp` but that does not seems to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, it seems that the following is achieving what I need:

```
import {  h, defineComponent, resolveComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
setup(props, ctx) {
   const myComp = resolveComponent('comp');
   return () => h(myComp, {
       "onUpdate:myProp": (evt) => {
         console.log(evt);
       }
   });
})
```